# Swapping between two WAV Files

Tags: c, audio, microcontroller, wav, esp32

I am trying to swap between two different WAV files, one that is repeating all the time, the second file plays only one time if a condition is true (certain acceleration values). Unfortunately first swap to the conditioned one works but not back to the default file.
Sometimes a strange grumble appears after trying to swap back to default - I believe this could be reasoned by some loops trying to play the default sound but something kicks it of the loop.

What I mean: it swaps back to the default sound, enters the loop, but after a few loops comes nothing. See:

```
12:57:38.727 -> Channels :1
12:57:38.727 -> Sample Rate :22050
12:57:38.727 -> Byte Rate :44100
12:57:38.727 -> Block Align :2
12:57:38.727 -> Bits Per Sample :16
12:57:38.727 -> Data Size :42718
12:57:38.727 -> In loop
12:57:38.727 ->  | GyX = 11 | GyY = 6 | GyZ = -3
12:57:38.727 -> In loop
12:57:38.727 ->  | GyX = 11 | GyY = 5 | GyZ = -4
12:57:38.727 -> In loop
12:57:38.727 ->  | GyX = 11 | GyY = 5 | GyZ = -4
12:57:38.727 -> In loop
12:57:38.727 ->  | GyX = 11 | GyY = 6 | GyZ = -4
12:57:38.727 -> In loop
12:57:38.727 ->  | GyX = 10 | GyY = 6 | GyZ = -3
12:57:38.727 -> 
12:57:38.727 -> 
12:57:38.727 -> 
12:57:38.727 -> 
12:57:38.727 -> 
12:57:38.727 -> 
12:57:38.727 -> 
12:57:38.727 ->
```

I use a slightly changed sketch from this tutorial: https://www.xtronical.com/i2s-ep3/
It was made for only playing one WAV file so I extended the loop to choose between WAV files.
Though I am not capable understanding everything inside the sketch - kinda new to microcontrollers. Tell me if you need anything else.

My Code:

```
// 
// Title: SD Card Wav Player
//
// Description:
//    Simple example to demonstrate the fundementals of playing WAV files (digitised sound) from an SD Card via the I2S 
//    interface of the ESP32. Plays WAV file from SD card. To keep this simple the WAV must be stereo and 16bit samples. 
//    The Samples Per second can be anything. On the SD Card the wav file must be in root and called wavfile.wav
//    Libraries are available to play WAV's on ESP32, this code does not use these so that we can see what is happening.
//    This is part 3 in a tutorial series on using I2S on ESP32. See the accompanying web page (which will also include
//    a tutorial video).
//
// Boring copyright/usage information:
//    (c) XTronical, www.xtronical.com
//    Use as you wish for personal or monatary gain, or to rule the world (if that sort of thing spins your bottle)
//    However you use it, no warrenty is provided etc. etc. It is not listed as fit for any purpose you perceive
//    It may damage your house, steal your lover, drink your beers and more.
//
//    http://www.xtronical.com/i2s-ep3
//
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
// Includes

    #include "SD.h"                         // SD Card library, usually part of the standard install
    #include "driver/i2s.h"                 // Library of I2S routines, comes with ESP32 standard install
  
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    #include<Wire.h>
    #define SDA 21
    #define SCL 22
    const int MPU_addr=0x68;  // I2C address of the MPU-6050
    int16_t GyX,GyY,GyZ;

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Defines
 
//    SD Card
          #define SD_CS          5          // SD Card chip select
   
//    I2S
          #define I2S_DOUT      25          // i2S Data out oin
          #define I2S_BCLK      27          // Bit clock
          #define I2S_LRC       26          // Left/Right clock, also known as Frame clock or word select
          #define I2S_NUM       0           // i2s port number

// Wav File reading
          #define NUM_BYTES_TO_READ_FROM_FILE 1024    // How many bytes to read from wav file at a time

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// structures and also variables
//  I2S configuration

      static const i2s_config_t i2s_config = 
      {
          .mode = (i2s_mode_t)(I2S_MODE_MASTER | I2S_MODE_TX),
          .sample_rate = 44100,                                 // Note, this will be changed later
          .bits_per_sample = I2S_BITS_PER_SAMPLE_16BIT,
          .channel_format = I2S_CHANNEL_FMT_RIGHT_LEFT,
          .communication_format = (i2s_comm_format_t)(I2S_COMM_FORMAT_I2S | I2S_COMM_FORMAT_I2S_MSB),
          .intr_alloc_flags = ESP_INTR_FLAG_LEVEL1,             // high interrupt priority
          .dma_buf_count = 8,                                   // 8 buffers
          .dma_buf_len = 64,                                    // 64 bytes per buffer, so 8K of buffer space
          .use_apll=0,
          .tx_desc_auto_clear= true, 
          .fixed_mclk=-1    
      };
      
      // These are the physical wiring connections to our I2S decoder board/chip from the esp32, there are other connections
      // required for the chips mentioned at the top (but not to the ESP32), please visit the page mentioned at the top for
      // further information regarding these other connections.
      
      static const i2s_pin_config_t pin_config = 
      {
          .bck_io_num = I2S_BCLK,                           // The bit clock connectiom, goes to pin 27 of ESP32
          .ws_io_num = I2S_LRC,                             // Word select, also known as word select or left right clock
          .data_out_num = I2S_DOUT,                         // Data out from the ESP32, connect to DIN on 38357A
          .data_in_num = I2S_PIN_NO_CHANGE                  // we are not interested in I2S data into the ESP32
      };
      
      struct WavHeader_Struct
      {
          //   RIFF Section    
          char RIFFSectionID[4];      // Letters "RIFF"
          uint32_t Size;              // Size of entire file less 8
          char RiffFormat[4];         // Letters "WAVE"
          
          //   Format Section    
          char FormatSectionID[4];    // letters "fmt"
          uint32_t FormatSize;        // Size of format section less 8
          uint16_t FormatID;          // 1=uncompressed PCM
          uint16_t NumChannels;       // 1=mono,2=stereo
          uint32_t SampleRate;        // 44100, 16000, 8000 etc.
          uint32_t ByteRate;          // =SampleRate * Channels * (BitsPerSample/8)
          uint16_t BlockAlign;        // =Channels * (BitsPerSample/8)
          uint16_t BitsPerSample;     // 8,16,24 or 32
        
          // Data Section
          char DataSectionID[4];      // The letters "data"
          uint32_t DataSize;          // Size of the data that follows
      }WavHeader;
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

//  Global Variables/objects    
    
    File WavFile;                                 // Object for root of SD card directory
    static const i2s_port_t i2s_num = I2S_NUM_0;  // i2s port number    

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
int start=1;
long long timestamp;

void setup() {    
  Wire.begin(SDA, SCL);
  Wire.beginTransmission(MPU_addr);
  Wire.write(0x6B);  // PWR_MGMT_1 register
  Wire.write(0);     // set to zero (wakes up the MPU-6050)
  Wire.endTransmission(true);
  pinMode(16, INPUT);
  Serial.begin(115200);                               // Used for info/debug
  SDCardInit();
  i2s_driver_install(i2s_num, &i2s_config, 0, NULL);
  i2s_set_pin(i2s_num, &pin_config);
  // get the wav file from the SD card
  WavFile = SD.open("/wavfile.wav");                   // Open the wav file
  if(WavFile==false)
    Serial.println("Could not open 'wavfile.wav'");
  else
  {
    WavFile.read((byte *) &WavHeader,44);               // Read in the WAV header, which is first 44 bytes of the file. 
                                                        // We have to typecast to bytes for the "read" function
    DumpWAVHeader(&WavHeader);                          // Dump the header data to serial, optional!
    if(ValidWavData(&WavHeader))                        // optional if your sure the WAV file will be valid.
      i2s_set_sample_rates(i2s_num, WavHeader.SampleRate);      //set sample rate 
  }
  
}


void loop()
{  
  Wire.beginTransmission(MPU_addr);
  Wire.write(0x3B);  // starting with register 0x3B (ACCEL_XOUT_H)
  Wire.endTransmission(false);
  Wire.requestFrom(MPU_addr,14,true);  // request a total of 14 registers
  GyX=Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();  // 0x43 (GYRO_XOUT_H) & 0x44 (GYRO_XOUT_L)
  GyY=Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();  // 0x45 (GYRO_YOUT_H) & 0x46 (GYRO_YOUT_L)
  GyZ=Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();  // 0x47 (GYRO_ZOUT_H) & 0x48 (GYRO_ZOUT_L)
  Serial.print(" | GyX = "); Serial.print(GyX/1325);
  Serial.print(" | GyY = "); Serial.print(GyY/1325);
  Serial.print(" | GyZ = "); Serial.println(GyZ/1325); 



  if((abs(GyX/1325) > 12 || abs(GyY/1325) > 12) && start==1){
    Serial.println("Start: 1 and Sensor");
    WavFile = SD.open("/coolsaber.wav");
    start=0;
    play_file();
  }
  if (start==0)  {
    Serial.println("Start: 0 and Sensor");
    timestamp=millis();
    while(abs(millis()-timestamp)<1000) {
      PlayWav();
    } 
    WavFile = SD.open("/wavfile.wav");
    start=1;
    play_file();
  }
  PlayWav();
  Serial.println("In loop");

}
void play_file(){
  if(WavFile==false)
    Serial.println("Could not open File");
  else
  {
    WavFile.read((byte *) &WavHeader,44);               // Read in the WAV header, which is first 44 bytes of the file. 
                                                        // We have to typecast to bytes for the "read" function
    DumpWAVHeader(&WavHeader);                          // Dump the header data to serial, optional!
    if(ValidWavData(&WavHeader))                        // optional if your sure the WAV file will be valid.
      i2s_set_sample_rates(i2s_num, WavHeader.SampleRate);      //set sample rate 
  }
}


void PlayWav()
{
  static bool ReadingFile=true;                       // True if reading file from SD. false if filling I2S buffer
  static byte Samples[NUM_BYTES_TO_READ_FROM_FILE];   // Memory allocated to store the data read in from the wav file
  static uint16_t BytesRead;                          // Num bytes actually read from the wav file which will either be
                                                      // NUM_BYTES_TO_READ_FROM_FILE or less than this if we are very
                                                      // near the end of the file. i.e. we can't read beyond the file.

  if(ReadingFile)                                     // Read next chunk of data in from file if needed
  {
    BytesRead=ReadFile(Samples);                      // Read data into our memory buffer, return num bytes read in
    ReadingFile=false;                                // Switch to sending the buffer to the I2S
  }
  else
    ReadingFile=FillI2SBuffer(Samples,BytesRead);        // We keep calling this routine until it returns true, at which point
                                                      // this will swap us back to Reading the next block of data from the file.
                                                      // Reading true means it has managed to push all the data to the I2S 
                                                      // Handler, false means there still more to do and you should call this
                                                      // routine again and again until it returns true.
}

uint16_t ReadFile(byte* Samples)
{
    static uint32_t BytesReadSoFar=0;                   // Number of bytes read from file so far
    uint16_t BytesToRead;                               // Number of bytes to read from the file
    
    if(BytesReadSoFar+NUM_BYTES_TO_READ_FROM_FILE>WavHeader.DataSize)   // If next read will go past the end then adjust the 
      BytesToRead=WavHeader.DataSize-BytesReadSoFar;                    // amount to read to whatever is remaining to read
    else
      BytesToRead=NUM_BYTES_TO_READ_FROM_FILE;                          // Default to max to read
      
    WavFile.read(Samples,BytesToRead);                  // Read in the bytes from the file
    BytesReadSoFar+=BytesToRead;                        // Update the total bytes red in so far
    
    if(BytesReadSoFar>=WavHeader.DataSize)              // Have we read in all the data?
    {
      WavFile.seek(44);                                 // Reset to start of wav data  
      BytesReadSoFar=0;                                 // Clear to no bytes read in so far                            
    }
    return BytesToRead;                                 // return the number of bytes read into buffer
}

bool FillI2SBuffer(byte* Samples,uint16_t BytesInBuffer)
{
    // Writes bytes to buffer, returns true if all bytes sent else false, keeps track itself of how many left
    // to write, so just keep calling this routine until returns true to know they've all been written, then
    // you can re-fill the buffer
    
    size_t BytesWritten;                        // Returned by the I2S write routine, 
    static uint16_t BufferIdx=0;                // Current pos of buffer to output next
    uint8_t* DataPtr;                           // Point to next data to send to I2S
    uint16_t BytesToSend;                       // Number of bytes to send to I2S
    
    // To make the code eaier to understand I'm using to variables to some calculations, normally I'd write this calcs
    // directly into the line of code where they belong, but this make it easier to understand what's happening
    
    DataPtr=Samples+BufferIdx;                               // Set address to next byte in buffer to send out
    BytesToSend=BytesInBuffer-BufferIdx;                     // This is amount to send (total less what we've already sent)
    i2s_write(i2s_num,DataPtr,BytesToSend,&BytesWritten,1);  // Send the bytes, wait 1 RTOS tick to complete
    BufferIdx+=BytesWritten;                                 // increasue by number of bytes actually written
    
    if(BufferIdx>=BytesInBuffer)                 
    {
      // sent out all bytes in buffer, reset and return true to indicate this
      BufferIdx=0; 
      return true;                             
    }
    else
      return false;       // Still more data to send to I2S so return false to indicate this
}

void SDCardInit()
{        
    pinMode(SD_CS, OUTPUT); 
    digitalWrite(SD_CS, HIGH); // SD card chips select, must use GPIO 5 (ESP32 SS)
    if(!SD.begin(SD_CS))
    {
        Serial.println("Error talking to SD card!");
        while(true);                  // end program
    }
}

bool ValidWavData(WavHeader_Struct* Wav)
{
  
  if(memcmp(Wav->RIFFSectionID,"RIFF",4)!=0) 
  {    
    Serial.print("Invalid data - Not RIFF format");
    return false;        
  }
  if(memcmp(Wav->RiffFormat,"WAVE",4)!=0)
  {
    Serial.print("Invalid data - Not Wave file");
    return false;           
  }
  if(memcmp(Wav->FormatSectionID,"fmt",3)!=0) 
  {
    Serial.print("Invalid data - No format section found");
    return false;       
  }
  if(memcmp(Wav->DataSectionID,"data",4)!=0) 
  {
    Serial.print("Invalid data - data section not found");
    return false;      
  }
  if(Wav->FormatID!=1) 
  {
    Serial.print("Invalid data - format Id must be 1");
    return false;                          
  }
  if(Wav->FormatSize!=16) 
  {
    Serial.print("Invalid data - format section size must be 16.");
    return false;                          
  }
  if((Wav->NumChannels!=1)&(Wav->NumChannels!=2))
  {
    Serial.print("Invalid data - only mono or stereo permitted.");
    return false;   
  }
  if(Wav->SampleRate>48000) 
  {
    Serial.print("Invalid data - Sample rate cannot be greater than 48000");
    return false;                       
  }
  if((Wav->BitsPerSample!=8)& (Wav->BitsPerSample!=16)) 
  {
    Serial.print("Invalid data - Only 8 or 16 bits per sample permitted.");
    return false;                        
  }
  return true;
}


void DumpWAVHeader(WavHeader_Struct* Wav)
{
  if(memcmp(Wav->RIFFSectionID,"RIFF",4)!=0)
  {
    Serial.print("Not a RIFF format file - ");    
    PrintData(Wav->RIFFSectionID,4);
    return;
  } 
  if(memcmp(Wav->RiffFormat,"WAVE",4)!=0)
  {
    Serial.print("Not a WAVE file - ");  
    PrintData(Wav->RiffFormat,4);  
    return;
  }  
  if(memcmp(Wav->FormatSectionID,"fmt",3)!=0)
  {
    Serial.print("fmt ID not present - ");
    PrintData(Wav->FormatSectionID,3);      
    return;
  } 
  if(memcmp(Wav->DataSectionID,"data",4)!=0)
  {
    Serial.print("data ID not present - "); 
    PrintData(Wav->DataSectionID,4);
    return;
  }  
  // All looks good, dump the data
  Serial.print("Total size :");Serial.println(Wav->Size);
  Serial.print("Format section size :");Serial.println(Wav->FormatSize);
  Serial.print("Wave format :");Serial.println(Wav->FormatID);
  Serial.print("Channels :");Serial.println(Wav->NumChannels);
  Serial.print("Sample Rate :");Serial.println(Wav->SampleRate);
  Serial.print("Byte Rate :");Serial.println(Wav->ByteRate);
  Serial.print("Block Align :");Serial.println(Wav->BlockAlign);
  Serial.print("Bits Per Sample :");Serial.println(Wav->BitsPerSample);
  Serial.print("Data Size :");Serial.println(Wav->DataSize);
}

void PrintData(const char* Data,uint8_t NumBytes)
{
    for(uint8_t i=0;i<NumBytes;i++)
      Serial.print(Data[i]); 
      Serial.println();  
}
```

Comment: where in the code is ReadingFile ever set back to true after being set to false?

Comment: Hey Stark, afer calling the playWav() in the loop it's set to true in this functions first line

Comment: back to the book on static variables